# Integration over a surface are

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

[image]

When I start trying to solve this problem, I don't know where I go wrong. I think it should be in what I consider as my $r(\theta, \rho)$

$r(\theta,\rho)=(\rho cos(\theta), \rho sin(\theta), 0)$,
$0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$  and  $0\leq \rho \leq 1$

Which should be the correct r (I honestly don't get any of the answer choices)?

Thank you in advance for any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if correct, but I'll try:

I assumed z to be 0 everywhere, since the intersection's z-coordinate is zero everywhere, and then I used [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem)

Answer should follow easily to be d)

Comment: Thank you Makina, I am not 100% either to be honest (if that is the answer), but I will review Green's theorem since it has been some time.

Comment: No problem, I hope that this is the correct answer, coz I failed to find the 3-d version for the Green's theorem.

Comment: @Makina That's called Stokes's theorem.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel thank you, I guess using that theorem we still arrive at the green's theorem result with dz components being equal to zero.